# Printing a web page from Windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is it possible to use a windows batch script to open a web page and print its contents to your default printer? Something simple as this:

```
@echo off
start /d IEXPLORE.EXE www.google.com
```

and now I want to send that page to the printer.  But I am not sure of the syntax nor was I able to find anything specific or helpful on the web.

Does anyone know if it's possible to print a web page using a windows batch command?

Answer (score 1):

Not from an [iexplore switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330728%28VS.85%29.aspx), but vbscript will work:

```
Const PRINT = 6
Const DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
Const BUSY=4

Dim oIExplorer
Set oIExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIExplorer.Navigate "http://www.stackoverflow.com/"
oIExplorer.Visible = 1

Do while oIExplorer.ReadyState <> BUSY
wscript.sleep 1000
Loop

oIExplorer.ExecWB PRINT, DONTPROMPTUSER
```

Comment: Thanks Sean.  The vbScript works.  However, I tried to navigate to another page and print that and I keep getting a MS Error that asks me if I want to Send Error Rpt to MS and then it closes IE.  All I did was repeat the section of code where you state:

oIExplorer.Navigate "http://www.yahoo.com/"
oIExplorer.Visible = 1

Do while oIExplorer.ReadyState <> BUSY
wscript.sleep 1000
Loop

oIExplorer.ExecWB PRINT, DONTPROMPTUSER


So it prints Stack Overflow and then goes to Yahoo and prints that page.  The code is able to navigate to Yahoo.com but is not able to print the page.  Any suggestions?

Comment: [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691264.aspx) are all the magic numbers available. I notice there is a PRINT2 (49) - that may have different effects than the PRINT (4). the list shows it as an updated print command